# How to re-execute a module which is being imported in a powershell script after making changes to the module

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script `a.ps1` which imports a module `b.psm1`. Now for testing purposes, when I make some changes to `b.psm1`, and then run the `a.ps1` script, the changes made in the Module are not reflected in the execution. I guess its because its using the previous version of the Module that it imported. So how do I avoid this? How do I tell it to load the module again?
Kindly give suggestions apart from dot sourcing the module file in the script

Comment: Have you checked what switches the `import-module` command has? Have a look at the `-force` switch.

Comment: yea, I just did. And it worked. Should have read the docs more carefully. Thanks for the help